# In Google Sheets onedit function, abort function if variable cell value is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, jsoneditor

I have a search page driven by checkboxes and an onEdit function in a Google Sheet. It allows users to search a dataset, select a single row (record) from the search results, and append a user code if assuming responsibility for that record. It includes a dialog box asking them if they wish to proceed before the function executes. If yes, it proceeds and resets. If no, it aborts and waits for a new command.

The data setup is:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chkbox | Name | Age | Place | User |

The user code data enters in column E of the dataset. What I need is for the onEdit function to abort if another user has already assumed responsibility for that record. In other words, say User A searches and selects a record for "Sarah Stout," and clicks the checkbox to code that as "USER A" to take responsibility for Ms. Stout (and USER A will appear for anyone else's subsequent searches). However, User B has already done the same thing, so in column E, it already says USER B. I want the function to abort so that User A override that from the search page.

I tried:

> **if (NOT(ISBLANK($E$6))) return;**

because the first search result would appear in row 6 (but the first row with a checkbox), but that didn't work. I just don't understand the syntax as well in this, so I don't know how to specify the column. Here's the onEdit code

```js
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;
if (e.value != 'TRUE') return;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ignored_sheets = ['Sheet2','Sheet3','ReportOutput'];
if (ignored_sheets.includes(sheet.getName())) return;
var row_index = e.range.rowStart;
var row = sheet.getRange('B' + row_index + ':D' + row_index).getDisplayValues().flat();
if (row[1] == '') return;
var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
.alert("Do you wish to mark this record?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if (result != SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
sheet.toast("Request canceled.");
sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
return;}
sheet.toast("Request initiated.");
sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
sheet.getRange('B3').clearContent();
sheet.getSheetByName('ReportOutput').appendRow(row);
sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').setActiveCell('B3');
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?
Where am I going wrong?

I know I'll need an IF statement, and I know I'll need something like this if they check the box when they shouldn't:

```js
    {sheet.toast("Unable to overwrite data.");
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
    return;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

If I've understood your question clearly, you want your `onEdit(e)` function to abort running if the value on column `E`, based on the selected row, already contains a user code.

### Sample Code:

> *You need to add these lines of code after the `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` line.*

```
  //If the selected row on column E is not blank
  if(e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),5).getValue().length > 0){ 
    sheet.toast("Process aborted.\ \""+e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),5).getValue()+"\" has already taken responsibility for \""+e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue()+"\"");
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue(false);
    return;
  };
```

### Sample Demonstration

- Sample Sheet:

> [image]

- Result:

*Say **"User A"** checks the box for `Sarah Stout` but the column `E` for Sarah already contains **USER B***

> [image]

*After a split second*

> [image]

Comment: @MUNGHOLMI Feel free to correct me if ever I've got it wrong.

Comment: Wow, this did exactly what I wanted, and even better than I thought it could, since you also has variable text in the message. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, and especially the speed of your answer!
The only change I made is that I put the code after the ignored sheets code. I thought that if your code came before that, it could trigger on other pages where users *can* edit Column E freely.  Was that necessary on my part, or would the "ignore sheets" if condition have stopped the script from taking any action even if the new code had come first?

Comment: @MUNGHOLMI You're welcome. Sorry I've missed that one, yes, it is necessary to have "ignore sheets" before you run the code as I think it is the main condition to run before condition in checking the column `E`.

Comment: You've been super-helpful, but I wonder if you'd be able to point me aright for 1 more thing. Some users take on a record, then decide they need to un-assign themselves. I want the OutputReport sheet (where the appendRow executes & the usercode is added) to stay hidden so users can't break the sheet. Could I create another IF loop for USER-A's search page that says: IF for a row, ColE = USER A, & they select that row's checkbox (as if assigning USER A again), trigger dialog box, "Cancel this request?" and if yes, deleteRow on OutputReport tab where ColB = ColB in the selected search result?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think you can try that way.